# Find orbits of SU(2) adjoint representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

I am new to group theory, I can't understand, how to find orbits of adjoint representation of $SU(2)$ group. I appreciate any help, thank you in progress

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you know the definition of orbit? Do you know what an adjoint representation is?

Comment: @lisyarus I know all the definitions, at least, I think I do, but I can't imagine how to put it into practice.

Comment: If you're familiar with quaternions $\Bbb H$ and the fact $\mathrm{SU}(2)\cong\mathrm{Sp}(1)$, it'd make everything much easier.

Comment: @arctictern unfortunately I'm not familiar with quaterions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to think about linear algebra rather than group theory. The Lie algebra of $SU(2)$ consists of all skew-Hermitian matrices (i.e. matrices $X$ such that $X^*=-X$) and the adjoint action of $A$ maps $X$ to $AXA^{-1}$. Now think about what linear algebra tells you about looking at such matrices up to conjugation by a unitary matrix (i.e. up to the choices of an oriented orthonormal basis).